# Scraping external website within main project with python scrapy framework

Tags: python, python-2.7, web-scraping, scrapy

I have been looking for a better way to scrape external website from another a main source website. To better explain it let me use an example with yelp.com to explain what am trying to do (though my target is not yelp).

1. I would scrape title and address
2. visit link that titles leads to to get company website
3. I would like to extract emails from source code of the main website. (I know its difficult, but i am not crawling all pages i am assuming most site have contact in their url e.g site.com/contact.php)
4. The point is while scraping from yelp and storing data in a field, I want to get external data from a companies main website.

Below is my code can't figure out how to do it using scrapy.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from comb.items import CombItem, SiteItem

class ComberSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "comber"
    allowed_domains = ["example.com"]
    query = 'shoe'
    page = 'http://www.example.com/corp/' + query + '/1.html'
    start_urls = (
        page,
    )
    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r'corp/.+/\d+\.html'), restrict_xpaths=("//a[@class='next']")),
                  callback="parse_items", follow=True),
             )


    def parse_items(self, response):

        for sel in response.xpath("//div[@class='item-main']"):
            item = CombItem()
            item['company_name'] = sel.xpath("h2[@class='title']/a/text()").extract()
            item['contact_url'] = sel.xpath("div[@class='company']/a/@href").extract()[0]
            item['gold_supplier'] = sel.xpath("div[@class='item-title']/a/@title").extract()[0]
            company_details = sel.xpath("div[@class='attrs']/div[@class='attr']/span['name']/text()").extract()

            item = self.parse_meta(sel, item, company_details)
            request = scrapy.Request(item['contact_url'], callback=self.parse_site)
            request.meta['item'] = item

            yield request

    def parse_meta(self, sel, item, company_details):

        if (company_details):
            if "Products:" in company_details:
                item['products'] = sel.xpath("./div[@class='value']//text()").extract()
            if "Country/Region:" in company_details:

                item['country'] = sel.xpath("./div[@class='right']"
                                        + "/span[@data-coun]/text()").extract()
            if "Revenue:" in company_details:
                item['revenue'] = sel.xpath("./div[@class='right']/"
                                        + "span[@data-reve]/text()").extract()
            if "Markets:" in company_details:
                item['markets'] = sel.xpath("./div[@class='value']/span[@data-mark]/text()").extract()
        return item

    def parse_site(self, response):
        item = response.meta['item']
        # this value of item['websites'] would be http://target-company.com, http://any-other-website.com
        # my aim is to jump to the http://company.com and scrap data from it's contact page and
        # store it as an item like item['emails'] = [info@company.com, sales@company.com]

        # Please how can this be done in this same project
        # the only thing i can think of is store the item['websites'] and other values of item and make another project
        # even with that it would still not work because of the allowed_domains and start_urls 

        item['websites'] = response.xpath("//div[@class='company-contact-information']/table/tr/td/a/@href").extract()
        print(item)
        print('*'* 50)
        yield item



"""

from scrapy.item import Item, Field


class CombItem(Item):
    company_name = Field()
    main_products = Field()
    contact_url = Field()
    revenue = Field()
    gold_supplier = Field()
    country = Field()
    markets= Field()
    Product_Home = Field()
    websites = Field()
    """
    #emails = Field() not implemented because emails need to be extracted from websites which is different from start_url
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you issue a `Request`, passing [`dont_filter=True`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=dont_filter#scrapy.spidermiddlewares.offsite.OffsiteMiddleware) would turn off the `OffSiteMiddleware` and the url would not be filtered with `allowed_domains`:

> If the request has the dont_filter attribute set, the offsite
>   middleware will allow the request even if its domain is not listed in
>   allowed domains.